# how load a image from listview to a detail activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-activity

Hello I have a listview in which I load my JSON text and a thumbnail image.
I've used code from the tutorial from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ and converted this from xml to load json.

Parsing text and images work in my listview but now I've added a second activity, like a detail view, in which I also want to show the same image as the thumbnail.
I use the ImageLoader class from lazylist tutorial.

The problem is that i cannot load this image in my detail view.
Does someone has suggestions how i can make this work?

My code CustomizedListView:

```
    `package com.example.androidhive;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.example.androidhive.JSONParser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {


    // url om request te maken
    private static String URL = "http://www.iappministrator.com/OBDE/webservice/android_deelnemers_items.php";



    // JSON Node namen
    static final String TAG_ITEMS = "items";
    static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
    static final String TAG_IMAGES = "images";

    // Nieuws JSONArray
    JSONArray newsArray = null;

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Hashmap voor listView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Maak een JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Pakt JSON string uit URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);

        try{
            // Pakt de Array van Nieuwsartikelen
            newsArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEMS);

            // Loop door alle Nieuwsartikels
            for(int i=0; i < newsArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = newsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Het plaatsen van elk json item in variabele
                String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                String message = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                String images = c.getString(TAG_IMAGES);

                // maak een nieuwe HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // voeg elk item child node in de Hashmap -> value
                map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
                map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                map.put(TAG_IMAGES, images);


                // voeg de HashList toe aan ArrayList
                newsList.add(map);
            }
        } catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, newsList, R.layout.list_row, 
                new String[]{TAG_TITLE, TAG_MESSAGE, TAG_DATE, TAG_IMAGES}, new int[] {
                R.id.title, R.id.artist, R.id.duration, R.id.list_image});        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                String date = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration)).getText().toString();
                String message = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist)).getText().toString();
                //String images = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).getText().toString();
                //ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail); // thumb image
                String images = ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).getImageMatrix().toString();
                //String images = ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).toString();
                //String images = ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image)).getContext().toString();

                // Start de nieuwe intent

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                //Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) in.getParcelableExtra(TAG_IMAGES);

                in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, title);
                in.putExtra(TAG_DATE, date);
                in.putExtra(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
                in.putExtra(TAG_IMAGES, images);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });     
    }   
}`
```

The code of the secondActivity:

```
    package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.ImageGridActivity.ImageAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

    // JSON node keys
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGES = "images";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);


        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String title = in.getStringExtra(TAG_TITLE);
        String date = in.getStringExtra(TAG_DATE);
        String message = in.getStringExtra(TAG_MESSAGE);
        String images = in.getStringExtra(TAG_IMAGES);
        //Bitmap bitmap = in.getParcelableExtra(TAG_IMAGES);
        //ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_label);
        TextView lblDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_label);
        TextView lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_label);
        ImageView lblImages = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.images_label); 
        //TextView lblImages = (TextView) findViewbyId(R.id.images_label);

        // loader image
        //int loader = R.drawable.loader;
        System.out.println("Ja en nu werkt het niet meer");

        // image url
        //String image_url = "http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/5614379_460s.jpg";

       //ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
        //-imgLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.TAG_IMAGES), lblImages);
        System.out.println("Error? haha bam jammer dan:");
       //imgLoader.DisplayImage(images, lblImages);
        System.out.println("Plaatjes?:"+ images);

        lblTitle.setText(title);
        lblDate.setText(date);
        lblMessage.setText(message);
        //lblImages.setImageURI(Uri.parse(images));

        //ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
        //imageLoader.DisplayImage(images,lblImages);

        //lblImages.setImageResource(images);
        //imageLoader.displayImage(images);
        //lblImages.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        //lblImages.setImageResource(R.drawable.bitmap);
        //lblImages.setImageResource(images);
        /*if (d instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
            //Maybe more code here?
            lblImages.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }*/
        //lblImages.setImageResource(images);
        //lblImages.DisplayImage(images);
        //lblImages.DisplayImage(images);
    }
}
```

the lazyAdapter:

```
`package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d, int listRow, String[] strings, int[] is) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.TAG_TITLE));
        artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.TAG_MESSAGE));
        duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.TAG_DATE));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.TAG_IMAGES), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this in the customized listview

```
TAG_ITEMS = "items";
static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
static final String TAG_DATE = "date";
static final String TAG_IMAGES = "images";

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                          HashMap<String, String> map = newsList.get(position);

                        Intent in = new Intent(SingleMenuItemActivity.this, org.scout.android.library.LibraryDetail.class);
                        in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, map.get(TAG_TITLE));
                        in.putExtra(TAG_MESSAGE, map.get(TAG_MESSAGE));                         
                        in.putExtra(TAG_DATE, map.get(TAG_DATE));
                        in.putExtra(TAG_IMAGES, map.get(TAG_IMAGES));

                        startActivity(in);
```

And in you single menu item class get the extra and display image like so:

```
Intent in = getIntent();
final String image_url = in.getStringExtra(TAG_IMAGES);


ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ID);
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
imageLoader.DisplayImage(iamge_url, imgv);
```

Comment: That's ok, I had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Here I propose you a much cleaner way to do this(at least in my opinion).
This would be the code to list all views:

```
public class ListFiles extends ListActivity {
private List<String> dirEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
File[] files;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    File dir = new File(i.getStringExtra("directory"));

    if (dir.isDirectory())
        files = dir.listFiles();

    this.dirEntries.clear();

    for (File file : files)
        this.dirEntries.add(file.getPath());

    ArrayAdapter<String> dirList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.file_row, this.dirEntries);
    this.setListAdapter(dirList);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int pos, long id) {
    File clickedFile = new File(this.dirEntries.get(pos));
    Intent i = getIntent();
    //Detect what view was clicked
    i.putExtra("clickedFile", clickedFile.toString());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
}
```

}

Here is the code for the clicked view details:

```
public class ImageManipulation extends Activity {
static final String CAMERA_PIC_DIR = "/DCIM/CAMERA";
ImageView image;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.board);

    image = new ImageView(this);
    this.addContentView(image, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + CAMERA_PIC_DIR;

    Intent i = new Intent(this, ListFiles.class);
    i.putExtra("directory", dir);

    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((requestCode == 0) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        String tmp = data.getExtras().getString("clickedFile");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmp);
        processImage(bmp);
    }
}

private void processImage(Bitmap bmp) {


    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

}

In my code I'm using standard adapter for the list view but I'm sure is very easy to adapt what you did to this.Good Luck!!!!